# How to track the time between scale-up and scale-down events in a Spring app deployed on Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, autoscaling

I have a Spring application deployed on Kubernetes  and it's configured for autoscaling using KEDA . I would like to track the time duration between the scale-up and scale-down events for each pod in my application. Specifically, I want to record this information in a file for later analysis.

I tried this method it get executed every 2 minutes and I dont think it getting me any closer to what i want

```
    private final Map<String, LocalDateTime> scaleUpTimes = new HashMap<>();

        public void checkPods() {
            try {
                String command = "kubectl get pods -o json";
                Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

                // parse JSON output
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(stdInput.readLine());
                JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("items");

                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject pod = items.getJSONObject(i);
                    String podName = pod.getJSONObject("metadata").getString("name");
                    JSONObject podLabels = pod.getJSONObject("metadata").getJSONObject("labels");

                    // check if this pod belongs to the deployment
                    if (!"consumer-app".equals(podLabels.optString("app"))) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    String podStatus = pod.getJSONObject("status").getString("phase");

                    if ("Running".equals(podStatus) && !scaleUpTimes.containsKey(podName)) {
                        System.out.print("uppppppppp");
                        System.out.print(podStatus);
                        System.out.print(podName);

                        scaleUpTimes.put(podName, LocalDateTime.now());
                    } else if (!"Running".equals(podStatus) && scaleUpTimes.containsKey(podName)) {
                        System.out.print("scaledownn");
                        LocalDateTime scaleUpTime = scaleUpTimes.get(podName);
                        Duration duration = Duration.between(scaleUpTime, LocalDateTime.now());

                        // write to file
                        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\fold\\scale_up_events.arff", true);
                        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);

                        // write data
                        printWriter.println(
                                scaleUpTime.getMonth() + "," +
                                        scaleUpTime.getDayOfWeek() + "," +
                                        scaleUpTime.getHour() + "," +
                                        "scale_up," +
                                        duration.toMinutes()
                        );

                        printWriter.close();

                        // remove entry from map
                        scaleUpTimes.remove(podName);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Im expecting something like this

```
January,Monday,15:00,45 (mounth,day,time of the scaleup,how much the pod stayed up)
January,Monday,9:00,10
January,Monday,9:00,4
January,Monday,4:00,8
January,Tuesday,15,14
January,Tuesday,19,14
```

Comment: You want time API , https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gjHmdC-BW0Q2vXiQYmp1rzPU497sybNy/view?usp=drivesdk